# Store Raphael papers in html object's id

Tags: javascript, raphael

So I have some papers called "paper_0", "paper_1", etc. and I want to store them this way:

```
<h2 id="paper_0" onclick="doThing(this.id, 'myFunction')">Name of this thing</h2>
```

and in my javascript file:

```
//some code here
function doThing(id, func){
   currentId = id; //store current game
   func(); //this would create paper_0 **error**
   //some code here
}

function removePaper(){
   currentId.remove(); // **error**
}
```

so I have these 2 errors because *id* and *func* are both strings.

Any suggestion how can I store the paper **objects**?
Or can I give IDs to papers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in a function name, not an actual function.

Try this instead:

```
function doThing(id, func){
   currentId = id; //store current game

   if(func == "myFunction") myFunction(currentId);

   //...
}
```

You can store the objects in a global variable:

```
var papers = array();

function myFunction(id) {
    papers.push(id);
}
```

To remove elements from an array, you can do this: [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-a-javascript-array)

```
function removePaper(id){
    papers.splice(array.indexOf(id), 1);
}
```

You may modify this dog object to suit your paper needs:

```
var myDog = {

    "name" : "Spot",

    "bark" : function() { alert("Woof!"); },

    "displayFullName" : function() {
        alert(this.name + " The Alpha Dog");
    }
};

myDog.displayFullName(); 

myDog.bark(); // Woof!
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer! So after that I can use papers[0].remove() ?

Comment: Thanks but I would like to call the remove() method of the paper object.